# Is it possible to use aks custom headers with the azurerm_kubernetes_cluster resource?

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I'm looking at setting up a cluster of GPU nodes on AKS.

In order to avoid installing the nvidia device daemonset manually, apparently I can register for the `GPUDedicatedVHDPreview` and send `UseGPUDedicatedVHD=true` with AKS custom headers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/gpu-cluster).

I understand how to do this on the command line, but I don't understand how I can do it using the `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` terraform provider.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, at the time of writing, this isn't possible yet, as indicated by this open issue: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6793